# The most efficient way to store mapping of pairs

Tags: c++, boost, hashmap

I have to store a mapping of pairs to double:

```
boost::unordered_map<pair<int, int>, double> P;
```

I found access to the map is the bottleneck of the algorithm.

I insert values only once (in the order of tens of thousands of pairs). I sometimes update values and sometimes just do a lookup.

What are the ways to optimize the running time of lookup and update of the values?

**EDIT:**

Here is how I loop up the data:

```
p = make_pair(u, v);
q = P[p];
```

I found that the second line takes much more time that making a pair, and because I'm looking up many times for many keys it takes a lot of time.

Comment: Maybe use a sorted vector or a flat map?

Comment: how do you find, how do you update? `find` should be amortized constant time.

Comment: Why are you using a pair as the key? The hashing function will be the cause of your problem, but depending on your usage you may be better off using a different container.

Comment: Vector is much more cache friendly, so as suggested above, try a sorted vector.

Comment: "I found access to the map is the bottleneck" -- can you be more precise? is the hash function taking up the majority of the time, or the actual lookup in the data structure?

Comment: @KerrekSB Do you mean to sort a vector of tuples (int, int, double) and then access it using `find`?

Comment: @SergeyIvanov: Access it using `lower_bound` (although the critical size at which binary search trumps linear search may be surprisingly large -- measure!).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to combine the two integers into a single one, and use this one as a key. If you use the entire value range of `int` (assuming 4 bytes), a `long long` (assuming 8 bytes) may contain 2:

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
long long combined = (static_cast<long long>(a) << 32) | b;
```

Of course, if the values would fit in a `short`, you can use smaller data types. It can be advisable to use fixed-size types like `std::int32_t` for clarity and portability.

It can already be enough to adapt the hash function to combine the `first` and `second` members of `std::pair` in a different way. For that, it would be good to know more precisely *which part* of the lookup takes up the most time.

In case the hash function itself isn't the problem, a different data structure such as `boost::flat_map` could be worth a try.